# генерация JSON и передача на сервер

Tags: android

Добрый день подскажите как создать JSON файл и отправить его на http сервер через POST.

```
JSONObject bot = new JSONObject();
            try {
                instabot.put("Login", Login);
                instabot.put("Password", Password);
               }
```

как сохранить в файл json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создавать файл json, чтобы передать его на сервер, не нужно. Достаточно отправить его как обычную строку. В строку JSONObject можно превратить методом toString.

Вот самый простой пример:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new RequestTask().execute("http://www.site.ru/login.php"); // скрипт, на который посылаем запрос
}

public String getJSON(String login, String pass) // получаем json объект в виде строки
{
    JSONObject bot = new JSONObject();
    try {
        bot.put("Login", login);
        bot.put("Password", pass);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bot.toString();
}

public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // ключ - "json", параметр - json в виде строки
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", getJSON("userlogin", "userpass")));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8");
            postMethod.setEntity(entity);
            return hc.execute(postMethod, res);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exp=" + e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String res) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        // res - ответ сервера

        super.onPostExecute(res);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Ожидание");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
}
```

Обработать запрос можно, например, на PHP:

```
<?php
$json = $_POST['json']; // получаем json объект
$array = json_decode($json, true); // преобразуем его в ассоциативный массив
// получаем из него данные
$login = $array['Login'];
$pass = $array['Password'];
// дальше уже делаем то, что нужно
file_put_contents('login.txt', "$login\n$pass");
?>
```

Для отправки POST-запроса можно, например, использовать библиотеку Retrofit 2. В Интернете много примеров работы с ней.

Comment: Если есть какой-нить пример скиньте пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: А какую библиотеку надо ставить чтобы все это заработало?Именно retrofit? Я пытаюсь установить apache lib ... пока по нулям )

Comment: Для этого кода нужен HttpClient: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio. Но всё-таки предпочтительнее использовать более современные библиотеки, насчёт них я Вам подсказать, к сожалению, не могу.